# How to Solve Numba Lowering error?

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I have a function, which I am trying to speed up using the @jit decorator from Numba module. For me it is essential to speed this up as much as possible, because my main code calls upon this function for millions of times. Here is my function:

```
from numba import jit, types
import Sweep    #My own module, works fine


@jit(types.Tuple((types.complex128[:], types.float64[:]))(types.complex128[:], types.complex128[:], types.float64[:], types.float64[:], types.float64))
def MultiModeSL(Ef, Ef2, Nf, u, tijd ):
  dEdt= np.zeros(nrModes, dtype=np.complex128)
  dNdt0= np.zeros(nrMoments, dtype=np.complex128)
  Efcon = np.conjugate(Ef)

  for j in range(nrModes):
    for n in range(nrMoments):
      dEdt +=  0.5 * CMx[:,j,n,0] * dg * (1+ A*1j) * Nf[n] * Ef[j] * np.exp( 1j* (Sweep.omega[j]-Sweep.omega) *tijd)
      for k in range(nrModes):
        if n==0:
          dNdt0 += g* CMx[j, k, 0,:] * Efcon[j] * Ef[k] * np.exp( 1j* (Sweep.omega[k]-Sweep.omega[j]) *tijd) 
        dNdt0 += dg*(1+A*1j) * CMx[j,k,n,:] * Nf[n] * Efcon[j] * Ef[k] * np.exp( 1j* (Sweep.omega[k]-Sweep.omega[j]) *tijd) 

  dEdt += - 0.5*(pd-g)*Ef +     fbr*Ef2  + Kinj*EAinj*(1 + np.exp(1j*(u+Vmzm)) ) 
  dNdt = Sweep.Jn - Nf*ed - dNdt0.real
  return dEdt, dNdt
```

The function works perfectly well, without the Jit decorator. However, when I run it with the @jit, I get this error:

```
numba.errors.LoweringError: Failed at object (object mode frontend)
Failed at object (object mode backend)
dEdt.1
File "Functions.py", line 82
[1] During: lowering "$237 = call $236(Ef, Ef2, Efcon, Nf, dEdt.1, dNdt0, tijd, u)" at /home/humblebee/MEGA/GUI RC/General_Formula/Functions.py (82)
```

Line 82 corresponds to the For loop with j as iterator.

Can you help me out?

***EDIT:***
Based on Peter's suggestion and combining it with Einsum, I was able to remove the loops. This made my function **3** times faster.  Here is the new code:

```
def MultiModeSL(Ef, Ef2, Nf, u, tijd ):
  dEdt= np.zeros(nrModes, dtype=np.complex128)
  dNdt0= np.zeros(nrMoments, dtype=np.complex128)
  Efcon = np.conjugate(Ef)
  dEdt = 0.5*  np.einsum("k, jkm, mk, kj -> j",  dg*(1+A*1j), CMx[:, :, :, 0],  (Ef[:] * Nf[:, None] ),  np.exp( 1j* (OMEGA[:, None]-OMEGA) *tijd))
  dEdt += - 0.5*(pd-g)*Ef + fbr*Ef2  + Kinj*EAinj*(1 + np.exp(1j*(u+Vmzm)) )

  dNdt = - np.einsum("j, jkm, jk, kj ", g, CMx[:,:,:,0], (Ef*Efcon[:,None]),  np.exp( 1j* (OMEGA[:, None]-OMEGA) *tijd))
  dNdt += -np.einsum("j, j, jknm, kjm, kj",dg, (1+A*1j), CMx, (Nf[:]*Efcon[:,None]*Ef[:,None,None]), np.exp( 1j* (OMEGA[:, None]-OMEGA) *tijd)  )
  dNdt += JN - Nf*ed
  return dNdt
```

Can you suggest more techniques to speed this up?

Comment: what's `nrModes`? I reckon this is an out-of-bound or index error issue, can you debug with the values within the loop that those are within the indexes?

Comment: @Anzel nrModes is a variable that is defined outside the function. Im using it as a global variable.  I dont think it's an out of bound or index error issue, because the function works perfectly well without the jit decorator. 
Still to be sure, I replaced all nrModes and nrMoments with 2  and the error remains the same.  
All the other variables such as Ef, Nf etc are declared using the nrModes and nrMoments, so their dimensions match. Im sure it's not an index error issue

Comment: but what about `CMx` type? Are you sure it's within bound? Your information is too LIMITED that no one will try to help. One suggestion to debug is to do explicit loops within your `CMx` assignment rather than like `CMx[:,j,n,0]` and you shall see whether they are out-of-bound of your jit Type declarations

Answer (score 2):

There may be other issues, but one is that referencing an array in a module namespace seems to currently be unsupported (simple repro below).  Try importing `omega` as a name.

```
In [14]: %%file Sweep.py
    ...: import numpy as np
    ...: constant_val = 0.5
    ...: constant_arr = np.array([0, 1.5, 2.])
Overwriting Sweep.py

In [15]: Sweep.constant_val
Out[15]: 0.5

In [16]: Sweep.constant_arr
Out[16]: array([ 0. ,  1.5,  2. ])

In [17]: @njit
    ...: def f(value):
    ...:     return value + Sweep.constant_val
    ...: 

In [18]: f(100)
Out[18]: 100.5

In [19]: @njit
    ...: def f(value):
    ...:     return value + Sweep.constant_arr[0]

In [20]: f(100)
LoweringError: Failed at nopython (nopython mode backend)
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'module'
File "<ipython-input-19-0a259ade6b9e>", line 3
[1] During: lowering "$0.3 = getattr(value=$0.2, attr=constant_arr)" at <ipython-input-19-0a259ade6b9e> (3)
```

Comment: Thanks. That definitely is one of the issues, which I have changed in my code now. I made a new variable outside the function OMEGA = Sweep.omega.copy() and this happens only once when importing the module, so I can live with it.  \\  However, @jit is still giving me the same lowering error  :( .. I will try to vectorize as suggested by Peter, but if you have some idea on the JIT decorator, im open to it

Answer (score 1):

I can't see from your code why this isn't vectorizable.  Vectorizing can speed up this kind of Python code by around 100x.  Not sure of how it does relative to jit.

It looks like you could, for instance, take your dEdt out of the loop, and compute it in one step with something like :

```
dEdt = 0.5 * (Cmx[:, :, :, 0] * dg * (1+A*1j) * Nf[:] * Ef[:, None] * np.exp( 1j* (Sweep.omega[None, :, None, None]-Sweep.omega) *tijd)).sum(axis=2).sum(axis=1) - 0.5*(pd-g)*Ef + fbr*Ef2  + Kinj*EAinj*(1 + np.exp(1j*(u+Vmzm)) )
```

(Though I don't really know what the dimensionality of your Sweet.omega is).

Comment: That looks great, but doesnt give the expected results. I will add some more info in my question, I hope you can help me with the dEdt formula and I will extend the same procedure for the dNdt formula.

Comment: Hi, I have editted my question. Now you can see an updated code, where I have used your suggestion combined with np.einsum().  the code runs 3 times faster.  Do you have other suggestions on speeding it up?

Comment: Well now that the loops are gone there's no need for initializing with zeros.  Also I think now that you're using einsum all the broadcasting-related reshaping ([:, None, :, :], etc) can go away.

Comment: Great.. Thanks man.  deleting the zeros, speeds up a tiny bit (but it matters on huge repitions). I don't agree on the broadcast-related reshaping. Those are essential to the calculations, otherwise I would multiply vectors elementwise, instead of matrices. Anyways, You have been a great help. Thank you.

Comment: You were right. I could leave out the reshaping.  Implemented and works like a charm.  Thanks a thousand times.