# Numba giving error for NumPy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, list-comprehension, numba

After watching a [SciPy talk on Numba](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1AwG0T4gaO0), my understanding is that if it is done with NumPy tools, it can be done with Numba (with a good chance of speeding it up).

However, as I experiment with Numba-fying some code, it looks like the simple JIT (1) has no trouble with list comprehension, but (2) can't make head or tail of `numpy.asarray()`.

When I run

```
import numba
@numba.jit
def squareTest(xlist):
    y = [x**2 for x in xlist]
    return y
```

it runs fine. But when I run

```
import numba
import numpy as np
@numba.jit
def squareTest(xlist):
    y = [x**2 for x in xlist]
    y1 = np.asarray(y)
    return y1
```

the IPython console gives me a long traceback, says there was a Lowering Error, and ends with

```
def squareTest(xlist):
    y = [x**2 for x in xlist]`  
    ^
```

I don't know the structure of the Numba module, but the very last part tells me that when it's going to turn the produced list into a NumPy array afterward, it then has trouble doing list comprehensions.

I checked

```
@numba.jit
def squareTest(xlist):
    y = list(range(20))
    y1 = np.asarray(y)
    return y1
```

and it ran with no trouble, so it looks like it can handle *either* list comprehension *or* `np.asarray()`, but not both.

My first guess was that the `njit` mode can handle everything NumPy, and the mode that is turned off by adding the `n` to the `jit` is what handles list comprehension. But no, the first code sample still works when it is changed to `njit`.

What is the problem here, and how can I Numba-fy functions that involve doing NumPy array operations to arrays that are most pythonically made with list comprehensions?

Comment: Inspirational speakers are great, but if you are after some actual knowledge, begin with [numpy+numba questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numpy+numba) that show what works and when. Outline: if there's a NumPy solution for your task, use that; keep Numba handy for iterative computations that NumPy can't vectorize.

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39379556/how-to-solve-numba-lowering-error

Comment: @user6655984 Yes, this specific thing could be done better with vectorization, but I'm using it as a micro version of something else that I want to try `@jit` on, as well. So this is not so much about optimizing the code as making it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numba might be able to handle list comprehensions sometimes, but the speaker in the "Numba - Tell Those C++ Bullies to Get Lost" talk that you linked made the point that for it to reach its potential, you need to write the code that you JIT in an un-pythonic manner.

It is very likely that when Numba JITs the code, it changes the order of operations, or even combines the operations, so that even though it can do a list comprehension on a list, and it can also turn a list into a NumPy array, it can't do both.

You need to replace the list comprehension command with an un-pythonic sequence of commands to do the same thing.