# How to solve numba lowering error with nested for loops?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, numba

I want to find the minimum value of a function over a product of arrays. I started with a simple nested for loop and comparison implementation. As numba helped me to gain high speedups in many other places of the code, I figured out that I would simply have to add the decorator on my simple grid search. An equivalent example would be the following piece of code:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit


@njit()
def test():

    xs = np.arange(0, 1, 0.1)
    ys = np.arange(0, 1, 0.1)

    res = [0]
    smallest_value = np.inf
    for x in xs:
        for y in ys:
            value = x*x + y*y
            if value < smallest_value:
                smallest_value = value
                res = [x, y]

    return res, smallest_value


if __name__ == "__main__":

    print(test())
```

Which works fine when I remove the decorator, but with it, I have the following error:

```
File "numba_error.py", line 20:
def test():
    <source elided>

    return res, smallest_value
    ^

During: lowering "res.2 = res" at numba_error.py (20)
```

I went through the following question: [How to Solve Numba Lowering error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39379556/how-to-solve-numba-lowering-error) but I do not have module to reference.

Comment: the type of `res` cannot be inferred. You must specify the type of the list. Please read the Numba documentation about the experimental support of lists. In the current code, the type of `res` mutates which is not supported by Numba (and likely never because of compilation).

Comment: @JérômeRichard It seems that the type of res is inferred thanks to ````res = [0]````. I have another error message with ````res = []```` stating that the type could not be inferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This small edit worked for me: using a tuple instead of a list.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit


@njit()
def test():

    xs = np.arange(0, 1, 0.1)
    ys = np.arange(0, 1, 0.1)

    res = (0,0)
    smallest_value = np.inf
    for x in xs:
        for y in ys:
            value = x*x + y*y
            if value < smallest_value:
                smallest_value = value
                res = (x,y)

    return res, smallest_value


if __name__ == "__main__":

    print(test())
```